# how is the daily first battle bonus multiplier chosen?

Tags: world-of-tanks

Every tank gets a special experience multiplier bonus for the first battle won on given day. I've seen this multiplier to be x2, x3, x5, but couldn't find any rule when is it which. Does it follow any rule as to which multiplier is used on given day, or is it random?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is based on the promotion that wargaming is currently running. Normally the bonus is 2x but on special days (mostly the weekend, but sometimes during special periods) the multiplier is increased.

Check the world of tanks homepage for currently running promotions.